# MVC: Refresh list on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, list

I have a `view model` with 4 `lists`. Lets call the lists Animals, Cars, Houses and Furniture.

These lists contain 4 different types of pre-defined search results. In my `view` I'm trying to create a `form` with 4 `check boxes` and a `submit button` (each check box representing a certain list). On submitting the form I'm trying to combine the selected lists to one list and represent them in the view. I've been able to concat several of these lists in the controller and send them to the view model (and then to the view), but not been able to decide which lists to select from the view.

If code is needed to elaborate I am more than willing to supply this as well :)

So my question is, how do I determine which checkbox relates to which list, how would i proceed filling the concatenated list and updating the view accordingly?

Any pointers on how to proceed? Thanks for all suggestions.

Current controller (`filterResult` is here set to be concated with furtniture and cars):

```
public ActionResult Index(ListPage currentPage, int? page)
    {
        List<ListItem> filterResult = new List<ListItem>();
        ListResult allListResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<>();
        ListResult carsResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<Cars>();
        ListResult furnitureResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<Furniture>();
        ListResult housesResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<Houses >();


        filterResult = furnitureResult.Items.Concat(carsResult.Items).ToList();

        var model = new ListPageViewModel(currentPage)
        {
            AllPages = allBaseEditorialPagesResult.Items,
            TotalMatching = allBaseEditorialPagesResult.TotalMatching,
            FilteredPages = filterResult,
            TotalFilteredMatching = filterResult.Count()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

So in short; I want to choose which results the filterResult is filled with from the view.

Comment: Is the question, 'how can I determine which checkbox relates to which list', or 'how do I select which list to display the concatenated results in'?

Comment: @ChimaOsuji Ah sorry. Its closer to your first suggestion, determining which checkbox relates to which list and then submitting it to the concatenated results.

Comment: @adamNature please add some code to clarify

Comment: @user449689 updated with current controller

Comment: @adamNature you can identify which checkbox is selected when these are posted to the server. You can then determine which list you want them to relate to --> e.g. checkbox_1 relates to list_1 --> if checkbox_1 is selected, add list_1 to results

Comment: @adamNature You should try using 3 instead of 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
{
<b>Animals</b>@Html.CheckBox("checkAnimals")
<b>Furniture</b>@Html.CheckBox("checkFurniture")
<b>Cars</b>@Html.CheckBox("checkCars")
<b>Houses</b>@Html.CheckBox("checkHouses")
<input type="submit" tabindex="2" class="btn" value="Apply filter" />
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(ListPage currentPage, int? page, bool checkAnimals = false, bool checkFurniture= false, bool checkCars= false, bool checkHouses= false)
{
    List<ListItem> filterResult = new List<ListItem>();
    ListResult allListResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<>();
    ListResult carsResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<Cars>();
    ListResult furnitureResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<Furniture>();
    ListResult housesResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<Houses >();
    ListResult animalsResult = _searchService.GetPagesByPageType<Animals>();
    if (checkAnimals)
        {
            filterResult = filterResult.Concat(animalsResult.Items).ToList();
        }
        if (checkFurniture)
        {
            filterResult = filterResult.Concat(furnitureResult .Items).ToList();
        }
        if (checkCars)
        {
            filterResult = filterResult.Concat(carsResult.Items).ToList();
        }
        if (checkHouses)
        {
            filterResult = filterResult.Concat(housesResult.Items).ToList();
        }

    var model = new ListPageViewModel(currentPage)
    {
        AllPages = allBaseEditorialPagesResult.Items,
        TotalMatching = allBaseEditorialPagesResult.TotalMatching,
        FilteredPages = filterResult,
        TotalFilteredMatching = filterResult.Count()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```